# How to assign value to a element in 2D list in python

Tags: python-3.7

For mentioned python code I am getting result as [[0,4,2],[0,4,2]]. Here '2', I am passing dynamically. I want result as [[0,1,2],[0,4,2]], how can I get this?

> > > a = [[0,1,2]]*2
> > >       a[1][1] = 4

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in a way you create 2d list `a`. It holds links to same strings in each row.
Proper way to create it:

`a = [[0,1,2] for i in range(2)]`

Found [here](https://snakify.org/ru/lessons/two_dimensional_lists_arrays/#section_2).